# Action creator is either called on render or cannot be called at all React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an action creator that needs some data passed to it to update the store:

action creator:

```
    export const addPokemonToTeam = pokemon => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.ADD_POKEMON_TO_TEAM,
        pokemon: pokemon
    }
}
```

reducer snippet:

```
        case actionTypes.ADD_POKEMON_TO_TEAM :
        return {
            ...state,
            myTeam: state.myTeam.concat([action.pokemon])

        }
```

But when I use this code in map dispatch to props:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return{
    onAddPokemonToTeamHandler: pokemon => 
      dispatch(myTeamActions.addPokemonToTeam(pokemon))
  }
}
```

And then pass it as an onClick function to a component:

```
     <TeamToggle
       displayStyle="add"
       onClick={() => this.props.onAddPokemonToTeamHandler(this.state.pokemon)}
       >
         Add to my team
      </TeamToggle>
```

Passing the prop like that, as an anonymous function, makes the code not execute at all, and I don't understand why. If I pass it without the anonymous function, it of course is executed as soon as the component is rendered. Any ideas on how to call the action creator only on click?

Comment: are there any errors in the console etc

Comment: Your onClick event is not fired. Everythink that you shown look fine.

Comment: how do you know it is not executing?

Comment: add some logging / debugging to confirm if it is firing or not - I can't see anything else wrong with it either

Comment: I know it's not firing because I'm using redux devtools for chrome and I see no store state update

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean its not firing, that only means its not updating.